# Passing 'this' into a cached click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in some uneditable file that binds a click handler to some items, as such:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".editThis", function(e) {
    var elemID = this.id;
    // etc...
});
```

In another file, I attempt to wrap a check around it before executing the function:

```
// Get event info
var clickEvent = $("#container").data('events').click[0];
var clickEvent_func = clickEvent.handler;
var clickEvent_selector = clickEvent.selector;

// Remove previous event and attach new one
$("#container").off("click", clickEvent_selector);
$("#container").on( "click", clickEvent_selector, function(e) {
    if (someValue) {
        clickEvent_func(e);
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
});
```

Due to the fact that there's no longer any context for the original function (I guess), I get an error on the first line when I try to run it. How do I get around this? Or is there a better way of accomplishing the check?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.data('events')` hasn't been available for a long time

Comment: @charlietfl 1.9.2 (not by choice!). I got the `.data('events')` thing off another SO question. Is there a newer, possibly backwards-compatible way to accomplish this?

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, can you rephrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.8 events were moved to [`$._data(element, 'events')`](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) and no longer stored on individual elements.

In order to pass in a new `this` you need to use [`function.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```js
$('#container').on('click', '.editThis', function(e) {
  console.log('Original handler');
  console.log('event type:', e.type);
  console.log('button id:', this.id);
});

// store reference to original event handler before using `off()`
var clickEvt = $._data($("#container")[0], "events").click[0],
  selector = clickEvt.selector,
  originalHandler = clickEvt.handler;

var clickCount = 0;

$('#container')
  .off('click', selector, originalHandler)
  .on('click', selector, newHandler);

function newHandler(e) {
  if (clickCount) {
    // call original handler with current `this` and event object
    originalHandler.call(this, e);
  } else {
    console.log('First click')
    clickCount++;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button class="editThis" id="btn">
    Click me twice
  </button>
</div>
```